# How to provide type definition while pushing the element into array using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to avoid the using of 'any' as type definition while pushing the element into array. I tried to provide the type but I am getting an error. Here is the sample code

```
interface answerProps {
    state: string;
    answer: string;
  }

  const results: Array<string> = [];
  !isEmpty(answers) &&
    answers.map((item: any) => results.push(`${item.state} : ${item.answer}`));
```

As per the above code , I wanted to avoid of using any while mapping the array element.

Comment: need more information about `answers`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `answerProps` interface while mapping the array.

```
interface answerProps {
  state: string;
  answer: string;
}

const results: Array<string> = [];
!isEmpty(answers) &&
  answers.map((item: answerProps) => results.push(`${item.state} : ${item.answer}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
interface answerProps {
  state: string;
  answer: string;
}

const answers: answerProps[]  = []
const results = answers.map(item => `${item.state} : ${item.answer}`);
```

**note 1**
there are 2 ways of casting a typed array. For my example, I mainly used the 2nd casting method

- `const arr1: Array<string>`
- `const arr2: string[]`

**note 2**
in your given sample, `array.map` is not the correct method to use, try using `array.forEach` instead

**note 3**
`array.map` when used correctly, allows typescript to automatically identify the resulted type, and is great to avoid manually casting type to variables

**note 4**
(this is purely preferences) rather then guarding against empty array, try to refactor your code so that it will accepts empty array as valid. In the example I have given above, an empty answers will gets mapped to an empty results

Answer (score 0):

```
const results: Array<string> = [];
  !isEmpty(answers) &&
    answers.map((item: answerProps ) => results.push(`${item.state} : ${item.answer}`));
```

Change `any` to `answerProps` if it is the same type.

If it still shows an error, then try to provide a data type for the array such as define array `let answers:answerProps[]` or  `answers as answerProps[]`. But please make sure to have data with the same type.

By the way, use uppercase for the first letter when you define a class or an interface

ex: `AnswerProps`